# Javascript only works after page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some code that I found online that makes both divs on my website become equal lengths. However, this code only works after the page is refreshed and I have no idea what would cause this. Any help would be appreciated!

```
 // EQUAL HEIGHTS
$.fn.equalHeights = function(px) {
    $(this).each(function(){
        var currentTallest = 0;
        $(this).children().each(function(i){
            if ($(this).height() > currentTallest) { currentTallest = $(this).height(); }
        });
    if (!px && Number.prototype.pxToEm) currentTallest = currentTallest.pxToEm(); //use ems unless px is specified
        // for ie6, set height since min-height isn't supported
        if ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version == 6.0) { $(this).children().css({'height': currentTallest}); }
        $(this).children().css({'min-height': currentTallest}); 
    });
    return this;
};

// just in case you need it...
$.fn.equalWidths = function(px) {
    $(this).each(function(){
        var currentWidest = 0;
        $(this).children().each(function(i){
                if($(this).width() > currentWidest) { currentWidest = $(this).width(); }
        });
        if(!px && Number.prototype.pxToEm) currentWidest = currentWidest.pxToEm(); //use ems unless px is specified
        // for ie6, set width since min-width isn't supported
        if ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version == 6.0) { $(this).children().css({'width': currentWidest}); }
        $(this).children().css({'min-width': currentWidest}); 
    });
    return this;
};

 // CALL EQUAL HEIGHTS  
 $(function(){ $('#equalize').equalHeights(); });
```

Comment: use this code inside .ready block

Comment: Check the order in which you load your scripts. Are the scripts used in the function loaded before you use the function?

Comment: @samitha `$(function() { ... })` is the same as `$(document).ready(function() { ... })`. See [here](https://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery3).

Comment: You can't get the height & width before the window launches, so first time it won't work. When you refresh the window, you have the window so it can get the height & width.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behavior happens because the plugin was not well written. I've modified it for you and now it should work.

[Working DEMO](http://jqversion.com/#!/HFrRvZu)

Plugin script:

```
// EQUAL HEIGHTS
  $.fn.equalHeights = function(px) {
      var currentTallest = 0;
      $(this).each(function(){
          $(this).siblings().each(function(i){
              if ($(this).height() > currentTallest) { 
                currentTallest = $(this).height();
              }
          });
      });

      if (!px && Number.prototype.pxToEm) {
        currentTallest = currentTallest.pxToEm(); 
      }
      $(this).siblings().css({'height': currentTallest, 'min-height': currentTallest});
      return this;
  };
```

You can modify the `equalWidths` plugin to work as this plugin.

Comment: Thanks - I also changed the order and its working now :D

Answer (score 0):

put all your code in jquery ready function. inside ready function code executes when the DOM is ready

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//your code
});
```

Comment: As I mentioned in a comment, `$(function() { ... })` is the same as `$(document).ready(function() { ... })`, and he already put his code in a `$(function() { ... });`. Mentioned in [the API](https://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery3).

Comment: I tried this before posting and it didn't work! Thanks though.